# I need help to access to a variable in Devel -> Load in Drupal 7

Tags: php, arrays, templates, drupal, drupal-7

Im very stuck with this problem:

I have a module with some variables that i need to catch in a external template in php.

I create an array to travel all the variables like this:

> $campos_mostrables=array('title','biblio_year','other_fields','biblio_authors_field','biblio_contributors','biblio_secondary_authors_field',....)Then
>   i use a foreach($campos_mostrables as $campo_m)

My problem is when for example 'biblio_contributors' is an array, not a simple string. This variable has this estructure in Devel -> Load:

biblio_constributors (array, 2 element) 
      0 (Array, 19 elements) 
              name (String, 9 characters ) **NAME1**. 
      1 (Array, 19 elements) 
              name (String, 9 characters ) **NAME2**.

**I need to access to this "NAME1 and NAME2 in my template, but i dont know how to access to this info to print it.**

Please, someone can help me?

Thanks so much!!!

Comment: You should put the printscreen of the devel load, that would help. Also it's not clear what you want to do exactly. Do you need to get some info inside a template? Just in case you can get variables with variable_get.

Answer (score 0):

Did you used [Variable set and get](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7.x) method?
If you have got installed devel module, you can dump your vars using dpm() method.

`$myarray=array('a','b');
dpm($myarray);`

and check the structure of your data.